# Phase 10- Wild Card use

Tags: phase-10

Are you able to drop wildcard in the discard pile?
A player used this technique to not absorb as many points, as different player was about the phase on their next turn.
It did not seem fair... Valid move or not valid?
&
If a player drops a wildcard in the discard pile, can the next player pick up the wild card so they can win?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is allowed. From [the rules](https://www.unorules.com/phase-10-rules/):

> discard any card that you want onto the Discard Pile

A wild on top of the discard pile is the same as any other card, it can be picked up by thr current player:

> If turned up at the beginning (to form the Discard pile), the first player to start can pick it up.

Although that rule is about the beginning of a hand, the normal rules about drawing from the discard pile don’t give any indication that the wild is special or different.